# Преобразование указателя на одномерный массив в указатель на двумерный

Tags: эмулятор, массивы, указатели, c++

В общем, для чего всё это нужно: есть почти полностью реализованный  [эмулятор CHIP8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP-8). Оперативная память у него состоит из ячеек, размером в 1 байт, и предоставляет диапазон адресов от 000h до FFFh. Я её объявил как:

```
unsigned char memory[0x1000];
```

Видеопамять же находится в той же оперативной памяти с некоторым смещением, и занимает диапазон от F00h до FFFh.

Если к оперативной памяти удобно обращаться как к одномерному массиву, то к видеопамяти удобнее обращаться как к двумерному массиву типа `bool[][]` (потому, что дисплей монохромный, и его пиксели имеют два состояния — "чёрный" и "белый").

Как правильно и безопасно получить указатель на двумерный массив [32][64] из указателя на одномерный? Одномерный же массив получить легко:

```
bool *videomem = (bool *)memory + 0xF00;
```

А вот двумерный массив уже не получается:

```
bool *video_mem[64] = (bool *[64])memory + 0xF00;
```

Можно, конечно, создавать для видеопамяти отдельный массив (и многие программы адекватно работают), но это снижает точность эмуляции (некоторые программы могут писать напрямую в видеопамять CHIP8).

Comment: Вам нужно сделать массив указателей на строки, см. первый ответ в http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052818/create-a-pointer-to-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
unsigned char memory[0x1000];

const size_t video_mem_row_size = 64; // или 0x40, раз уж всё в hex
const size_t video_mem_offset = 0xF00;
typedef unsigned char video_mem_row[video_mem_row_size];

video_mem_row* video_mem = (video_mem_row*)(memory + video_mem_offset);
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/mpflzb

---

Если у вас 64 — это размер в *битах*, и вы оперируете битами, вам, судя по всему, понадобится немного другой код.

```
unsigned char memory[0x1000] = {}; // обязательно инициализируйте!

const size_t bits_in_byte = 8;
const size_t video_mem_offset = 0xF00;

const size_t video_mem_row_bitsize = 0x40;
const size_t video_mem_row_stride =
    (video_mem_row_bitsize + (bits_in_byte - 1)) / bits_in_byte;

typedef unsigned char video_mem_row[video_mem_row_stride];

video_mem_row* video_mem = (video_mem_row*)(memory + video_mem_offset);

const size_t video_mem_number_of_rows = 0x20;

bool get_video_bit(size_t row, size_t col)
{
    if (row >= video_mem_number_of_rows || col >= video_mem_row_bitsize)
        throw std::invalid_argument("index");
    unsigned char* p = &video_mem[row][col / bits_in_byte];
    unsigned char mask = ((unsigned char)1) << col % bits_in_byte;
    return *p & mask;
}

void set_video_bit(size_t row, size_t col, bool value)
{
    if (row >= video_mem_number_of_rows || col >= video_mem_row_bitsize)
        throw std::invalid_argument("index");
    unsigned char* p = &video_mem[row][col / bits_in_byte];
    unsigned char mask = ((unsigned char)1) << col % bits_in_byte;
    if (value)
        *p |= mask;
    else
        *p &= ~mask;
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/2BBcM1

---

Я бы посоветовал обернуть это в класс. Если хотите, можно написать индексаторы в духе `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: Компилится без предупреждений, но при обращении к видеопамяти приложение крашится. Вроде Bad Access (точно ошибку не могу поймать, потому что при краше ломаются аж дебаггер с QtCreator).

Comment: @Chupik: А у вас случайно `memory` не стековая переменная? :-P

Comment: @Chupik: Подождите, что значит «типа `bool`»? У вас один байт на пиксель или один упакованный бит, а байт адресует 8 пикселей?

Comment: Каюсь, ступил и нечаянно объявил переменную (которая уже была как член класса) второй раз внутри функции. Теперь все работает как надо, ничего не падает. :)

Comment: Да, у меня на каждый пиксель один бит.

Comment: А вы адресуете индексами байт или бит? Потому что у нас получается `video_memory[0][2]` — это не второй _бит_ (находящийся в нулевом _байте_), а второй _байт_ видеопамяти.

Comment: @VladD: когда работаю с ОЗУ - то работаю с байтами, когда с видеопамятью - то с битами.
Продебажил эмулятор - выводит графику правильно, но оперативную память использует нерационально (на каждый байт записывается 1 пиксель вместо 8).

Comment: @Chupik: Тогда смотрите обновлённый код, старый неправилен.

---
Снова обновил, мелкие улучшения и красивости.